# Возвращаемое значение главной функцией

Tags: c++

Вот возник вопрос по коду:

```
int main()
{
    ...
    system("Pause");    
    return 0;  // имеет ли смысл эта строчка после паузы?
    }
```

Нужно ли возвращать значение в главной функции, если делается системная пауза? Или данный пример считается кодом плохого стиля?

Comment: Функция, которая возвращает не `void`, всегда должна возвращать значение!

Comment: void - не возвращаемое значение! Это оператор, указывающий, что функция обращается в процедуру, т.е ничего не возвращает.

Comment: `void` - это спецификатор типа, означает "ничто" и в сях нет процедур. Здесь только функции, и функция, возвращающая void, тоже может вернуть значение - тот же `void`:

    void a(){}
    void b(){ return a(); }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Да, возвращаемое значение имеет смысл. Это пришло из философии Юникса, где программа своим кодом возврата сообщает другим программам, успешно ли она отработала. 0 считается индикатором успешного выполнения, остальные значения -- нет.

Если ваша программа работает "сама по себе", не в связке с другими, *в принципе* можно возвращать что угодно, но хорошим тоном всё равно считается возвращение нуля или не нуля в зависимости от того, успешно или нет отработала программа.

Если же ваша программа должна работать вместе с другими, как часть скрипта -- возврат разумного кода завершения (так называется значение, возвращаемое функцией `main`) обязателен!

По стандарту C++ в функции `main` *можно* опустить `return` (что равносильно `return 0`), но я бы не рекомендовал этого делать из соображений хорошего стиля.

Comment: Т.е завершение функции MAIN конструкцией return 0 - хороший стиль?

Comment: @LOLPADT: да.

Comment: Окай, в таком случае мне все понятно.

Answer (score 3):

Функция `main()` возвращает значение `int`. Поэтому `return` нужен в любом случае.

Comment: стандарт С++ разрешает не возвращать ничего в функции `int main(...)`

Comment: @delphist007, не обязательно. Сигнатуру главной функции можно продекларировать и так:

    void main(){}

Но это не совсем корректно.

Comment: @LOLPADT, на сколько я знаю, в gcc такое не скомпилируется.

Comment: @VladD, ну как минимум некрасиво это. Нехороший тон, другими словами.

Comment: >Поэтому return нужен в любом случае.

Если уж сильно придираться, то не просто return, а `return что_то_целочисленное` :), но вобщем - да, поддерживаю!

Comment: @mega, если уж придираться, то что_то_целочисленное_большее_или_равное 0. При чём если не было ошибки, то нужно вернуть 0.

Comment: >что_то_целочисленное_большее_или_равное 0

А вот это уже совсем не обязательно. Результатом `main` вполне может быть код из `message table`, формат которой предусматривает старшие 2 бита (severity code) установленным в `Warning`( 10 ) или `Error`( 11 ).

Comment: @delphist007: ага, в моём ответе по существу так и написано.

Answer (score 3):

Возвращаемое значение всегда нужно. Во-первых, паузу так никто не делает. Под Линуксом такой код неработоспособен. Я предлагаю просто сделать ожидание ввода. Можно через `getch()` или `while(!kbhit())` или еще как-то. Обратить внимание, что не все способы названные переносимы. Во-вторых, можно запросто убрать вызов `system` в процессе разработки программы и? В третьих, программа, по моему понятию, после `system` продолжает выполнение со следующей инструкции. Можете проверить это на практике.

Comment: Возможное решение (в тему пришлось) проблемы ожидания ввода в винде (вместо всех system("PAUSE") и т.п.)

      atexit((void (*)())getchar);

Пишете в начале программы. Срабатывает при exit/return-из-main в любом месте.

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к уже сказанному о коде возврата могу добавить, что корректно (осмысленно для окружения) завершить программу можно 4-мя способами.

Это уже рассмотренный оператор return, функции exit() и raise(), а также системный вызов _exit().

Действия при return и вызове exit() одинаковые. Подробности про exit(), _exit() и raise()
см. соответствующие man.

Проиллюстрировать это можно такой программкой:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void
fin()
{
  puts("atexit func");
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  atexit(fin);
  if (!av[1])
    _exit(puts("_exit") == EOF);
  else if (*av[1] == 'x')
    exit (puts("exit") == EOF);
  else if (*av[1] == 'r')
    raise(SIGTERM);
  return (puts("return") == EOF);
}
```

А вот ее результат

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ for i in x 1 '' r; do                               
> echo ./a.out $i; ./a.out $i; echo rc = $?; done
./a.out x
exit
atexit func
rc = 0
./a.out 1
return
atexit func
rc = 0
./a.out
_exit
rc = 0
./a.out r
Terminated
rc = 143
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$
```

Выводимый rc = ... это тот самый код возврата, которым программа "говорит" о том, как она завершилась. Традиционно 0 - это успешно.

Кстати, в windows коды возврата тоже используется. Например (переносимо для Makefile (!))

```
myprog && echo Success
```

в командной строке выведет `Success` только если `myprog` успешно завершилась.

Comment: >Действия при return и вызове exit() одинаковые

Это так в С, а в С++ - нет. При вызове exit() не происходит вызова деструкторов объектов, что может приводить к неприятным последствиям (например, к несброшенным буферам файловых потоков, незакрытым сетевым соединениям и т.п.)

Comment: @mikillskegg, спасибо, не знал. 

Видимо это следствие "среды runtime", реализованной в С++. Странно, что они не делают все это через atexit().

Comment: @mikillskegg, все больше проявляется картина, что С и С++ *достаточно разные* вещи (особенно в серьезных программах).

А exit(0) это может быть и нормальное завершение (из внутренних функций программы).

Согласен, в С++ можно бросить исключение, поймать его в main() и сделать return.

Еще один уровень усложнения... А ведь задумывался-то язык наверняка для упрощения программирования.

Comment: Кстати, деструкторы не будет вызываться только для автоматических объектов. Для внешних объектов деструкторы вызываться будут. А вообще, проблема безопасного аварийного завершения программы в С++ - очень интересная тема.

Кроме того, допустимы следующие конструкции

     int main() 
     try {
         ....
      }
     catch(...) {
         //some code
     }

Мне как ученому С++ нравиться своей неисчерпаемостью и постоянными загадками))))

Comment: @mikillskegg, а один мой знакомый (К.Т.Н. физик-экспериментатор) очень любил крутить кубик Рубика. 

Что характерно, часто собирал!

Comment: C++ покруче будет

Answer (score 2):

> Нужно ли возвращать значение в главной функции, если делается системная пауза?

Пауза и возвращаемое значение вообще никак не связаны. После нажатия любой клавиши пауза снимется и программа продолжится, как ни в чём ни бывало. Так что это условие лишнее.

По поводу return'а не буду повторять, уже ответили.

Answer (score -1):

```
return 0;
```

если небудет этой строчки то операционной системе всё равно "что-то" вернётся ("мусор"). некоторые компиляторы даже не дадут скомпилировать.

p.s. уж лучше выбрать "что вернуть" чем вернуть "мусор", если  не хочешь возвращать объяви main как void, но компиляторы опять таки могут ругаться

Comment: Мусор будет в С. В С++ вернется 0. А с void вообще может ошибку выдать.