# Как считать строку в цикле?

Tags: c++

При попытке использовать getline в цикле независимо от n дает ввести строку только один раз. Помогите исправить.

```
int n;
cin >> n;   
string s;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    getline(cin,s);         
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что считывание продолжается в той же строке, в которой было считано n

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;   
    cin.ignore();
    string s;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        getline(cin,s);
        cout << s<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Чуть выше была указана одна из ошибок, но я бы делал немного по-другому... К тому же, у вас ещё несколько нюансов по коду (хоть и не критичных - дело, скорее вкуса и оформления).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n;
    string s;

    cout<<"input number: "<<flush;
    cin>>n;

    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cout<<"input string: "<<flush;
        cin>>s;
        cout<<"string No. "<<i<<": "<<s<<"\n\n";

    }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Мой код отрабатывает без проблем. Добавил `cout`-ы для наглядности. Их можно убрать без вреда для кода.

Во-первых, при инициализации цикла, я бы в первичное выполнение записал `i=1` и в условие добавил `i<=n`, потому что это выглядит немного логичнее. Вместо `getline()`, я бы просто делал `cin>>s`. Ну а смысл? Хотя, если гуру С++ меня поправят и дадут объяснение - что ж, буду благодарен за науку. :)
А вот в конце кода у @koshachok есть фундаментальная ошибка. Функция `main()` должна возвращать значение! Это правильно. Да, компилятор это может сделать и за вас. Но доверять всё компилятору - дурной тон. Поэтому я добавил `return 0;`, чтобы сообщить, что программа отработала без ошибок. Передача аргументов в `main()` тоже может выполняться компилятором вместо пользователя, но я уже упоминал, что доверять компилю - дурной тон.

Опять же, это моё личное мнение. Я в С++ новчиок, поэтому готов выслушать адекватную (и главное обоснованную) критику. Я готов признавать свои ошибки. :)

Comment: cin >> s; будет считывать строку до пробела. а getline целиком. в моем случае в строке будут присутствовать пробелы

Comment: @Coldlot согласен, прошу прощения. Не знал этого нюанса - со строками ещё не работал. Проверил - действительно так. :)

Comment: 1. [cin vs getline](https://habrahabr.ru/post/246257/)


2. Ленивые программисты доверяют компилятору) а если интересно имеет ли это смысл, то прошу [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/167854/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9)

Comment: @koshachok благодарю за ссылочки. По поводу возвращаемого значения `main()` информация полезна, хоть отчасти и была мне известна. Но всё равно спасибо. И да - я не ленивый программист, поэтому я не доверяю компилятору. К тому же, мой препод на курсах меня учит правилам хорошего тона и больше доверять себе, нежели компилятору (чего стоят встраиваемые функции, которые компиль может не встроить и даже не скажет об этом). А вот статью на хабре почитаю завтра - сейчас уже как-то туго думается. :)